# Get folders name from Firebase Storage iOS(swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

[image]

I want to show list of files in my UICollectionView but I can get only list of items from folders. Help me please to get my folders name( paths) in Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folders are known as prefixes in the Firebase Storage API, and are returned when you [list the files in your storage bucket](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/list-files). From that documentation:

```
let storageReference = storage.reference()
storageReference.listAll { (result, error) in
  if let error = error {
    // ...
  }
  for prefix in result.prefixes {
    // The prefixes under storageReference.
    // You may call listAll(completion:) recursively on them.
  }
  for item in result.items {
    // The items under storageReference.
  }
}
```

Since `listAll` will list files/subfolders in the current directory only, you will have to recursively call it to also get nested folders.